How to notify the Debian team about an issue whose resolution looks unfinished? About dead keys bug, typing: ` + A gives `A and not À like before
A month ago, a regression happened in Debian 12 that caused dead keys not to work for a while.
It was a bug and they corrected it.
Things came back mostly to normal now, except for ` + A that doesn't type À anymore. Today, it produces:
`A

(if you have a VM with a previous Debian 12 version before May, or a Debian 11, you can check that it was working once: you got the À)
I would like to warn the Debian team that the resolution of the bug #1070745 isn't finished.
Because I'm not sure they are aware of this.
But I don't know the steps to follow to add such an entry to this issue.
Just send an e-mail? To which destination, with what title and what formalism?
Can you give me clues to do my report correctly?

In this instance I would report a new bug, referring to #1070745: the symptoms aren’t the same as the original bug.
To do this, use reportbug; since you know it’s probably caused by libglib2.0-0, specify that:
reportbug libglib2.0-0

Include all the information you have. The difference between Debian 11 and 12 might be significant — the original bug affected both.
If you can’t use reportbug, send a plain text email to submit@bugs.debian.org with
Package: libglib2.0-0
Version: 2.74.6-2+deb12u3

at the top of the body.
There’s no particular formalism, you can copy what you’ve written in your question. The title should summarise the issue: “Some dead keys no longer combine after fix for 1070745” for example.
See also How to report a bug in Debian.

Thanks! I did it. During the reporting process, reportbug libglib2.0-0 warned my that Your version (2.74.6-2+deb12u2) of libglib2.0-0 appears to be out of date. The following newer release(s) are available in the Debian archive:   bookworm-p-u: 2.74.6-2+deb12u3 but I couldn't do anything about that (it's an incoming update that we can expect in the next days, isn't it?). My report is about the 2.74.6-2+deb12u2. I hope they will take it into account. I've chosen important severity level.

Submitted as https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1072720 "Following fix #1070745, typing `A keys doesn't type an À anymore"

Thanks, you responded to my question perfectly and this post counts for an epilog in case of someone would stumble into that problem of À not forming anymore on a French keyboard.
It happens that very few of the french layouts available under GNOME do fire dead keys from their top row of keys.
only the selection of input source (legacy,variant) does.
The others, even if they have nice names (Français, Français Azerty...) don't.
